# White Space around repeating image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a good header with a repeating image but for some reason there is white space around it. I have tried many ways to remove it as you will see in my css but I cant figure it out.

My index file is basically just the Div Class Header.

CSS

```
.header{
position:relative;
width:100%; 
height: 478px;
float:left; 
background:url(../images/headBg.png) repeat-x;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
outline: none;
border: 0;
overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

This is what I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: can you give the screen shot or jsfiddle for the same

Comment: Can you make body{padding:0;margin:0} and try?

Comment: By default `<html>` and/or `<body>` have a margin set by the browser, maybe that's what you are seeing? try `body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` in your css

Comment: With your same code, i dont find any spaces between them. Jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/TFDw7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The white space is the default padding around a HTML page. Remove it by adding this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Demo with padding](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3XG/)

[Demo without padding](http://jsfiddle.net/RJWsT/)

Comment: What's with the padding? Its only the `margin`.

Comment: @Ruddy is that case in all browsers? I've always used both. Better safe than sorry

Comment: I have never seen a browser that uses padding by default, I don't think there is one. But I guess it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

As I just tested this and you already checked the main ones `margin:0` etc the white space will be on your image.

Check this out just to prove its not the code.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7XrQT/)

---

If you mean the spacing around the outside that would be the body margin:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will fix that.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7XrQT/1/)

---

So this would be your final version (removed all the `CSS` not needed.)

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7XrQT/3/)

Answer (score 1):

To remove that white space from around it, add the following code to your CSS

`body {margin:0; padding:0}`

That will remove the margin or padding (some browsers use margin, some padding) from the document, and your header will be flush to the window.

Answer (score 1):

This white "border" is caused by default margin/padding for `html` and `body` element. Set it to 0 too:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding you are seeing is most likely from the body not the Header.  You will need to do

`body{padding:0;margin:0;}`